# Tar Copy while skipping over a certain file pattern

Tags: linux, zsh, tar, cp

Goal: I am trying to create a command that copies all files except for any files that start with "." or "._"

BTW I am using Arch Linux 5.19 with ZSH

Scenario: I have a nearly full 1TB hard drive of legitimate files and basically copies of files and folders that start with "." and ".". for example: ".DS_Store" & ".$RECYCLING_BIN". I want to copy over and backup all the contents of this hard drive before I clean and delete those files types. However, since so many of those file types were created, they make the copy process take extremely long. I want to basically skip over those files when copying and only copy the files I want to preserve.

I have tried these commands #1

```
tar cf --exclude='/.*' - . | pv | (cd ~/test2; tar xf -)
```

I get this output

```
tar: --exclude=/.*: Cannot open: No such file or directory
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
0.00 B 0:00:00 [0.00 B/s] [>                                                             ]0%
```

and this command #2

```
tar cf -X .* - . | pv -s $(du -sb ~/test1 | awk '{print $1}') | (cd ~/test2; tar xf -)
```

Output

```
tar: -: Cannot stat: No such file or directory
tar: ./-X: file is the archive; not dumped
tar: Exiting with failure status due to previous errors
0.00 B 0:00:00 [0.00 B/s] [>                                                             ]0%            
tar: This does not look like a tar archive
tar: Exiting with failure status due to previous errors
```

Comment: The first parameter following the `-f` option is the name of the archive to be created. You set this name to be `--exclude='/.*'`. You probably want in change the order of your parameters.

Comment: What doneals24 said: `tar --exclude='/.*' -cf - . | pv | (cd ~/test2; tar xf -)` *untested*

Comment: @doneal24 that gets the command to run without errors, however it is still not skipping any files that start with . or ._

Answer (score 1):

The Correct command is

```
tar --exclude='**/.*' -cf - . | pv -s $(du -sb ~/test1 | awk '{print $1}') | (cd ~/test2; tar xf -)
```

1. As @doneals24 posted in a previous comment, the `-f` option is the name of the archive created - therefore you can indicate a dash as the file name
2. The `--exclude` option must follow this format `\*\*/.*` for the pattern to be valid